# Axios returning undefined data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, axios

Axios returning undefined data..?
I am trying to fetch the data from axios post request but it always returns either undefined or return the `firstname`. Is it because of some mismatch in data types?
This is the response I am getting when i try to print userdatas[i] 
{ id: 1,
  firstname: 'Leanne',
  lastname: 'Gram',
  password: '123',
  phone: '9474211442' }

**Server side**

```
const userdatas = [{
  id: 1,
  firstname: "Leanne",
  lastname: "Gram",
  password: "123",
  phone: "9474211442"
}]

app.post('/login', (req, res) => {
  let logindetail = {
    firstname: req.body.firstname,
    password: req.body.password
  }
  logindetail.firstname = logindetail.firstname.replace(/['"]+/g, '')
  logindetail.password = logindetail.password.replace(/['"]+/g, '')
  console.log(logindetail.firstname)
  var count = Object.keys(userdatas).length;
  for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    if (logindetail.firstname == userdatas[i].firstname && logindetail.password == userdatas[i].password) {
      res.send(userdatas[i]);
      console.log("Hello");
    }
  }
});
```

**Client Side**

```
handleSubmit = (e) => {
  alert(this.state.Firstname)
  e.preventDefault();
  axios.post('http://localhost:3001/login', {
    lastname: this.state.Lastname,
    firstname: this.state.Firstname,
    password: this.state.password,
    phoneno: this.state.phoneno
  }).then(res => alert(res.data.lastname))
}
```

Comment: `userdatas` is an `array` of  `object` not an `object`.  So your code should be this `var count = userdatas.length` instead of `var count = Object.keys(userdatas).length`.

Comment: I think that's why your `for loop` never runs

Comment: I guess the for loop is working fine .The issue is when server send the response of the post request I get an undefined value in client side

Comment: can you tell me the value in the `count`?

Comment: the value of count is 1

Comment: just console log the response and put it in your question. So we can see that what is the response

Comment: try returning something when there is no match or the forloop never runs basically this may even mean the user doesn't exists.

Comment: yeah the issue was the server was returning array datatype where as client was unable to identify the  data